# lxml .text returns None when string contains tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am a traversing complex XML file with millions of TU nodes and extracting strings from `<seg>` elements. Whenever `<seg>` element contains serialized tags, I get `None` object instead of a string.

Code that returns `None`:

```
source_segment = ET.parse(file).getroot().find('body').findall('tu')[0].findall('tuv')[0].find('seg').text
```

Sample content of `<seg>` element that causes the issue:

```
<seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />Coded glass plate<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>
```

Expected value of string variable `source_segment`:

```
<bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />Coded glass plate<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" />
```

I cant serialize `ET.parse(file).getroot().find('body').findall('tu')[0].findall('tuv')[0].find('seg').text` cause it is a `None` object. If I serialize only part `ET.parse(file).getroot().find('body').findall('tu')[0].findall('tuv')[0].find('seg')`, I get this:

```
b'<seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />Coded glass plate<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>\n      '
```

Sample XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="XXXXXXXX" creationtoolversion="100" o-tmf="XXXXXXXX" datatype="xml" segtype="sentence" adminlang="en-GB" srclang="en-GB" creationdate="XXXXXXXX" creationid="XXXXXXXX">
    <prop type="x-Note:SingleString"></prop>
    <prop type="x-Recognizers">RecognizeAll</prop>
    <prop type="x-IncludesContextContent">True</prop>
    <prop type="x-TMName">XXXXXXXX</prop>
    <prop type="x-TokenizerFlags">DefaultFlags</prop>
    <prop type="x-WordCountFlags">DefaultFlags</prop>
  </header>
  <body>
    <tu creationdate="XXXXXXXX" creationid="XXXXXXXX" changedate="XXXXXXXX" changeid="XXXXXXXX" lastusagedate="XXXXXXXX" usagecount="1">
      <prop type="x-LastUsedBy">XXXXXXXX</prop>
      <prop type="x-Context">0, 0</prop>
      <prop type="x-Origin">TM</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Translated</prop>
      <prop type="x-StructureContext:MultipleString">sdl:cdata</prop>
      <prop type="x-Note:SingleString">XXXXXXXX</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
        <seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />Coded glass plate<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />YYYYYYYYYYYYY<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

How do I extract the string from `<seg>` element when it contains serialized tags?

Comment: This does not answer my issue. XML node does not have method `.text_content()`. Also I need to preserve all inner tags in the extracted string.

Comment: Updated to include minimal reproducible example

Comment: I've managed to bypass this issue by serializing the whole `<seg>` node to byte object, converting byte object to string and regexing out the part between `<seg>` and `</seg>`. I cant believe there is no nicer solution.

Comment: Still not a real [mcve]. Don't just say "If I serialize..."; please show us the code. What is `current_TU`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a remnant from initial post.

Comment: It is not surprising that `.text` returns `None`. The `seg` element has no text content; it only contains child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I found is to convert the parent child to a string, passing parameter 'encoding=str' to avoid step of decoding bytes-like object to string and preserve UTF-8 symbols. Then regex out the  tags from the resulting string.

```
import re
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.parse('seg.xml').getroot()

seg_elem = root.find('body').findall('tu')[0].findall('tuv')[0].find('seg')

seg_string = ET.tostring(seg_elem, encoding=str)

# Regex to strip <seg> tags
seg_pattern = '(?<=<seg>).*?(?=</seg>)'
# Strip <seg> tags
final_string = re.search(seg_pattern, seg_string).group()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate about `<seg>`, depends on what you are interested in:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('seg.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def elem_to_string(child):
    print("Your wish as a string", ET.tostring(child).decode())

data = []
for elem in root:
    if elem.tag == "body":
        for child in elem.findall(".//seg"):
            elem_to_string(child)
            for sub_c in child.iter():
                print(sub_c.tag, sub_c.attrib, sub_c.text, sub_c.tail)
                row = sub_c.tag, sub_c.attrib, sub_c.text, sub_c.tail
                data.append(row)
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
     0                                   1     2                  3
0  seg                                  {}  None           \n      
1  bpt  {'i': '1', 'type': '14', 'x': '1'}  None  Coded glass plate
2  ept                          {'i': '1'}  None               None
3   ph            {'x': '4', 'type': '33'}  None               None
4  seg                                  {}  None           \n      
5  bpt  {'i': '1', 'type': '14', 'x': '1'}  None      YYYYYYYYYYYYY
6  ept                          {'i': '1'}  None               None
7   ph            {'x': '4', 'type': '33'}  None               None
```

Optional as a string:

```
Your wish as a string <seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />Coded glass plate<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>
Your wish as a string <seg><bpt i="1" type="14" x="1" />YYYYYYYYYYYYY<ept i="1" /><ph x="4" type="33" /></seg>
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to iterate contents of `<seg>`, I want to get it as a single string to manipulate.

Comment: I updated my answer and added also the branch as a string, but you can also easy manipulate the elements content, maybe easier as the regex function. Your choice. Hope you like it.

Comment: This actually matches what I came up with myself. Since I only need what's within `<seg>` as string, I also added this to get final string: 
`# Regex to strip <seg> tags
    seg_pattern = '(?<=<seg>).*?(?=</seg>)'
    # Strip <seg> tags
    returned_string = re.search(seg_pattern, returned_string).group()`